# Custom block javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, block

I know this is a bit of a dumb question.
Is it possible to make a custom block in javascript?
This is a block:

```
if(a==2){
    "block!"
}
```

This is a block:

```
for(;;){
    "block!"
}
```

Is it possible? I've never seen anything about this subject. Is there a possibility of this being implemented in es6?

It would be great for callbacks, It would allow you to do this:

```
foo{
    ...
}
```

Instead of this:

```
foo(function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Callbacks are basically a Function Expression passed by reference as parameter, I don't think you'd be able to reference a "block" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd like Ruby.

But no, there isn't a way to do this in JavaScript, and I haven't heard of any similar es6 features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels to create blocks in JavaScript but they're only useful if you want to `break` from them as afaik [you can't do anything else with them](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/labelled-blocks-useful/) and they don't have their own scope (with the exception of [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)).

```
foo: {
   // this is a block
   console.log(1);
   break foo;
   console.log(2); // never logged
}
```

Comment: Which is better, using a block scope inside a function and using `break;` or using a normal function and just do a `return;`?

Comment: The labelled block I've described here is not the same as a _function_; _functions_ have a big overhead in _JavaScript_. The fewer invocations you do, usually the more efficient your code.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, JavaScript only have function scope, global scope and there is no block scope just like C. So currently you can't do this. If you want a block you have to wrap it in a function, you have already listed.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this trick that gives you a block with it's own scope for a variable using try/catch:

```
try {
  throw 0;
} catch(variable) {
  //variable only exists in this block
  variable = 'my value';
  console.log(variable);
  //i can return from parent function here
}
//variable does not exist outside of the block
console.log(typeof variable);
```

There are performance considerations with using try/catch but it's useful because it still allows use of `return` or `break` if the block is inside a function or loop.